# Bounding the expectation of a function of a zero-mean random variable

Tags: random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I have a random variable $X$ with mean zero, $E[X]=0$, and finite second moment, $E[X^2]=\sigma^2<\infty$. I'm wondering if it's possible to show the following bound:
$$
E[(e^{X/2}-1)^2] \leq c\sigma^2,
$$
for some $c>0$. Is zero-mean sufficient? Or maybe I need more assumptions on the tails of $X$'s density or the size of $\sigma^2$. A couple things I've tried:

1. Intuitively, $(e^{x/2}-1)^2\approx (x/2)^2$ for $x$ near zero, which gives me hope. But I want something more rigorous.
2. It is **not** true that $(e^{x/2}-1)^2\leq cx^2$ for fixed $c$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. There's a crossover point at some positive $x$. However, that crossover increases as $c$ increases.
3. I tried playing with the moment generating function $M(t) = E[e^{tX}]$, and I found (by Jensen's inequality) that 
   $$
   E[e^{tX}-1] \geq 0,\quad t\in\mathbb{R}.
   $$
   But this seemed to bound things in the wrong direction.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the helpful discussion so far. I think it has helped me rephrase the question. It should be: given zero-mean $X$ with pdf $f(x)$ and second moment $\sigma^2<\infty$, find $c$ (that may depend on $X$) such that
$$
E[(e^{X/2}-1)^2] \leq c\sigma^2.
$$

Comment: Consider $X$ to be a random variable with PDF $f(x) = c/(1+x^4)$, where $c$ is chosen appropriately.

Comment: @stephen, Is this a counter example?

Comment: Yes it is a counterexample.

Comment: Since $(e^{x/2}-1)^2$ pretty much behaves like $e^x$ for $x$ large, I'm pretty sure you'd at least need f(x) to decay exponentially on the positive tail. The counterexample given above does not decay fast enough.

Comment: @Nimrod That's the point.  $E((e^{X/2}-1)^2) = \infty$.

Comment: Yes, I was in agreement.

Comment: @Nimrod Oops, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out something that worked for what I needed, which was slightly different from the question I'd originally posed. It was based on this inequality:
$$
e^x-1 \leq |x|\,e^x.
$$
Thus,
$$
e^X - 1 \leq |X|\,e^X,
$$
almost surely, which implies
$$
E[e^X-1] \leq E[|X|\,e^X].
$$
With $E[X]=0$ and $e^x$ convex, Jensen's inequality implies
$$
1 = e^0 = e^{E[X]} \leq E[e^X]\quad \Longrightarrow\quad 0 \leq E[e^X]-1 = E[e^X-1].
$$
Therefore
$$
0 \leq (E[e^X-1])^2 \leq (E[|X|\,e^X])^2.
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
(E[|X|\,e^X])^2 \leq E[X^2]\,E[(e^{X})^2] = \sigma^2\,E[e^{2X}],
$$
which finishes the derivation of what I ended up needing. Sorry for any confusion with the initial formulation.

Comment: Except that $e^x-1 \leq |x|\,e^x$ fails when $x<0$ hence nothing of the rest holds. (And anyway if $c$ is allowed to depend on the distribution of $X$ then the answer is trivial.)

Comment: @Did Hm. When $x<0$, $e^x-1<0$ and $|x|e^x>0$, so I don't see how it fails. And if something is trivial, then you should be able to show it. (The word "trivial" is my pet peeve.)

Comment: Oops sorry, the inequality in my comment holds but it is not the one you use. The one you use to apply Cauchy-Schwarz is $|e^x-1|\leqslant|x|e^x$, wrong when $x<0$, hence indeed "nothing of the rest holds", I am afraid.

Comment: Re "trivial", let me urge you to reconsider: if indeed $c$ can depend on $X$, *then the question is empty*. To wit, one is given two nonnegative functionals $A$ and $B$ of (the distribution of) $X$ and one asks if there exists a third functional $C$ such that $A(X)\leqslant C(X)B(X)$ for every $X$. Why, of course *one can find such a functional* $C$ (unless $B(X)=0$ and $A(X)>0$ is possible, which is not the case here), say $C(X)=A(X)/B(X)$... :-) So, what is the question?

Comment: If $X$ has mean zero, then $E[e^X-1]\geq 0$, so it's okay. Also, thank you for easily showing your "trivial" statement. When you use the word "trivial," you discourage people from participating in the discussion. It's a good idea to avoid the word, in most cases.

Comment: 1. I understood the first time that you did not like "trivial". Believe it or not, one can nevertheless use it, *albeit* with parsimony, hence I suggest that you leave the subject for now, even if it fascinates you and if you do have some peculiar theories about it. 2. I also suggest to seriously revise Cauchy-Schwarz. No, $Y\leqslant Z$ almost surely with $Z\geqslant0$ almost surely does not imply $E(Y)^2\leqslant E(Z)^2$. (Since you seem to be in a playful mode, I will let you find a counterexample.)

Comment: I've added more details to the derivation. I still don't think there's anything wrong with it. Being concerned about inclusive language is not being "playful." Broadly speaking, there is a culture of elitism and exclusivity in mathematics that creates barriers to dialog and conversation that disproportionately affect underrepresented groups. This is something worth fighting against.

Comment: Trivially, more details were needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a feeling that this couldn't possibly be true. Ignoring the mean zero condition, consider $X$ a constant. The left side increases exponentially, but the right quadratically. Now considering the mean zero condition again, if we just take $X=+x$ and $X=-x$ with both probabilities $1/2$, then $E[(e^{X/2}-1)^2]$ still scales exponentially, whereas $\sigma^2$ scales quadratically.

What goes wrong here is that $e^x$ blows up when $x$ blows up, so the taylor approximation is no good. If we instead look at $e^{ix}$, then using taylor estimates we find that the taylor remainder 
$$|R_n(x)| \leq \min \left(2|x|^n/n!, |x|^{n+1}/(n+1)!\right).$$
Thus
$$
E[|e^{iX}-1|^2] = E[|R_0(X)|^2] \leq E[\min(2,X)^2] \leq \min(4,\sigma^2).
$$
You may want to play with these kinds of results.

Comment: Actually $E[|e^{iX}-1|^2] \le 4$, because $|e^{iX}-1| \le 2$.  (Here I am assuming $X$ is real valued.)