# For zero-mean r.v. $X$ with var. $\sigma^2$, want to show $E[e^{2X}]\leq e^{2\sigma^2}$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ have zero mean, $E[X]=0$ and finite variance $E[X^2]=\sigma^2<\infty$. I'm trying to show 
$$
E[e^{2X}] \leq e^{2\sigma^2}.
$$ 
I started out with this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368366/bounding-the-expectation-of-a-function-of-a-zero-mean-random-variable/1369379), but I hadn't quite phrased it correctly. So this is the update. Several points worth noting. You can show that
$$
E[e^{X}] \leq E[X^2]^{1/2}\,E[e^{2X}]^{1/2} + 1.
$$
To see this, note that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
e^x-1 \leq |x|\,e^x,
$$
so that
$$
E[e^X-1] \leq E[|X|\,e^X].
$$
The zero-mean assumption implies $0\leq E[e^X-1]$, so Cauchy-Schwarz gives
$$
E[e^X-1] \leq E[X^2]^{1/2}\,E[e^{2X}]^{1/2}.
$$
Move $E[-1]=-1$ to the right side to finish the derivation. If you replace $X$ by $nX$, you get something that starts to look recursive,
$$
E[e^{nX}] \leq E[(nX)^2]^{1/2}\,E[e^{2nX}]^{1/2} + 1.
$$
The recursion suggests (to me) a power series lurking. Unfortunately, it gets recursive in a really ugly way because of the square roots. If there's a way to do it, I suspect there's a nicer way to show it than through the recursion. If $X$ is Gaussian, then the statement is true, which I discovered by looking at the [sub-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_random_variable) literature. I'd hoped some of their techniques would help, but so far they haven't. I'd prefer to avoid a Gaussian or sub-Gaussian assumption.

Comment: This is impossible from the start, with this upper bound or with any other finite one, since nothing in the hypotheses prevents $e^{2X}$ to be **non** integrable.

Comment: As an explicit example, given to you on the other page, shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:**

Say, $\sigma=1$.  Take $X_N$ to be the random variable taking values in $\left\{-\frac{1}{N},N\right\}$ for $N>1$ with $\text{Prob}\left(X_N=-\frac{1}{N}\right)=\frac{N^2}{N^2+1}$ and $\text{Prob}\left(X_N=N\right)=\frac{1}{N^2+1}$.  Obviously, $E\left[X_N\right]=0$ and $\text{Var}\left(X_N\right)=1=\sigma^2$.

Now, $E\left[X_N^n\right]=\frac{N^2\cdot(-1/N)^n+1\cdot N^n}{1+N^2}$.  If $n\geq 3$, then 
$$E\left[X_N^n\right]\geq\frac{N^n-1}{N^2+1}>N^{n-2}-N^{n-3}\,.$$
Thence, for $t>0$,
$$E\big[\exp\left(tX_N\right)\big] > \sum_{n\geq 3}\,\frac{t^n}{n!}\left(N^{n-2}-N^{n-3}\right)=\frac{N-1}{N^3}\left(\exp(Nt)-1-Nt-\frac{N^2t^2}{2}\right)\,.$$
That is, $E\big[\exp\left(tX_N\right)\big] \in \Omega\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\exp(Nt)\right)$ for large $N$, implying that $E\big[\exp\left(tX_N\right)\big]\to \infty$ as $N\to\infty$.  So, the bound $$E\big[\exp\left(2X_N\right)\big] \leq \exp\left(2\sigma^2\right)=\exp(2)$$ cannot hold for all $N>1$.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a very nice counterexample that I will surely use again.